# Does tailwind need upper version of php?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, php-8.1

I want to install a tailwind package for my laravel project.
I write in Terminal: `composer require composer require laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss --dev`

The error is:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I expect to install all packages correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "upper version"? Is that already the full error message? Also, how is this related to HTML or Bootstrap?

Comment: sorry ms.Nico , Its my fist time i ask a question in this community .. There in no related between bootstrap and html .. i just want to resolve my problem with install tailwind packages

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should include more details about the error message, and your attempts to resolve that error

Comment: What i shoud write?

Comment: They're not related. Laravel-presets package [requires](https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss/blob/main/composer.json) Laravel version 8. If you wish to install TailwindCSS itself, proceed [this guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel)

Comment: "What i shoud write?" - why not start with the **full and exact** error message? Usually, Composer tells you **why** the requirements could not get resolved

Answer (score 0):

This package looks like the same of Laravel Breeze one of the official starter kit.
I recommend to use Laravel Breeze or Laravel JetStream that are both served with tailwindcss, and you can use both as well with InertiaJS for Server Side Rendering and choosing between VueJS or ReactJS as javascript framework.

Check Out this:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits